# iOS 7 uitextview NSLineBreakByWordWrapping not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In iOS 7 I use new method to calculate the textview height,but it seems that it's not word wrapping, besides,the height is not the height of the text.

```
self.textview.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.textview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator= NO;
    self.textview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
//    [self.textview sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(296, 474)];
//    [self.textview.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] forWidth:296.0 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: self.textview.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle };
//
   CGSize size= [self.textview.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.textview.frame), MAXFLOAT)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:attributes
                                              context:nil].size;
    CGRect frame = self.textview.frame;
    frame.size = size;
    self.textview.frame= frame;
```

anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved the problem it's because the text has wrong white charter ,that is it replace white character with other character.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution? I have a similar issue where iOS7 is word wrapping differently with text that has multiple white spaces (in a row), boundingRectWithSize (and sizeWithFont) are inaccurate to what is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(295,99999);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [self.textview. sizeWithFont:self.textview..font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:self.textview.lineBreakMode];   

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = self.textview.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    self.textview.frame = newFrame;
```

Check image having your given text : http://screencast.com/t/Yqr6oSOvhN1

Comment: can you test the following in iOS7:  INDIANAPOLIS (AP) — Tim Bowers loved the outdoors. Hunting gave him the quiet time during which he could reflect on a busy life that included a new wife, a successful business and a baby on the way.
The Indiana man was enjoying that time while hunting for deer Saturday when he fell 16 feet from a tree and suffered a severe spinal injury that paralyzed him from the shoulders down. Doctors thought he might never breathe on his own again.
Confronted with that prognosis, Bowers' family made an unusual request of doctors at Fort Wayne's Lutheran Hospital: C

Comment: yes, its working perfectly... check I m uploading screen shot with your given text.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I had a wrong character space.
For replace I used:

```
message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00A0" withString:@“ "];
```